# How to converge multiple lines with \ to single line

Tags: c++, merge, line

I am looking at converging following output to single line, any suggestions will be helpful

```
$cat file
OBJECTS = 1.o \
2.o \
3.o \
4.o \
```

OUTPUT AND COMMAND RUN is

```
$cpp -x c file
OBJECTS = 1.o
2.o
3.o
4.o
```

I want output to be

```
OBJECTS = 1.o 2.o 3.o 4.o
```

cpp is a gnu cpp on any linux flavours
Any suggestions?

Comment: You mean joinging the lines? If so, what kind of editor are you using?

Comment: Show us what you have so far. (Read in lines till you find one that doesn't end with\.  Join them.  Output.  Loop.)

Comment: I am looking at CPP command which provides me an output in single line by reading the backslash character. Just to add CPP version 4.1.2 command produces output in single line but the CPP version 4.4 and later produces output in multiple lines

Comment: Right.  You want to use the cpp command to process text that is not a C or C++ program.  Well, maybe they stopped supporting that.  Anyway, this is nothing to do with C++ (and I bet you tagged your question "cpp" - which is not the "c pre-processor", but an alias for "C++").

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of syntax but you can try this pseudo code :

```
char ch;
char *s; // String s
While(EOF) {
    ch = readNextChar(); // read next char from file
    if(ch != '\\') s = strcat(ch); // append char to string
}
```

It will skip `\` from your file.

Comment: I am looking at a command with CPP which gives me a output in one line.

Comment: With older version of cpp 4.1 we get proper single line output but not with latest cpp ver 4.4 and later